# When to create the Entities in AndEngine

Tags: java, android, andengine

I've programmed a game with the following format

```
Sprite image1,image2;

@Override
protected void onPopulateScene(Scene pScene) {
      image1=new Sprite(....);
      image2=new Sprite(....);
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GLState pGLState, int pWidth, int pHeight) {
      image1.setPosition(0,pWidth/2);
      image2.setPosition(0,pHeight/2);
}
```

I'm receiving forcecrashes with NullPointerExceptions at the onSurfaceChanged. So I imagine that is happening because the surface changes before the onPopulateScene, but this never happens in my devices.

What is the correct way of avoiding that?

Thanks

Comment: Does it work on your devices? and you can just set an `if(){...}` saying if the images are not null then set the position. Alternatively why not set the position after creating the sprites since you are working with a static position.

Comment: Yes, for me it works. I can't use static position because I have banners that dinamically change their size and sometimes break the screen proportions

Comment: Remember also that the method uses the `X coordinate` then `Y coordinate` `image1.setPosition(pX, pY)`. just surround the methods with the if block that checks if the sprites are not null then set the position, or maybe run an `updateHandler` on them. Try one of those see if it can help.

Comment: Why not just wrap that in if(image1 != null)?